# Using Excel to generate significant numbers of Cypher statements for Neo4j data loading

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I will apologise right at the outset as I am sure my question is elementary! I am not a database man but I have an idea and only a graph database is going to do it - so i am learning right from the very beginning. I am using Neo4j 2.3 and building the blocks of my structure in org charts which I then convert into Excel - I am comfortable with Excel, I am an Engineer!

I use CONCATENATE within Excel to build my Cypher statements and generating the nodes works perfectly, so far so good.

I then used the same technique to build the Cypher statements for the relationships and when I trialled it using a single Cypher Statement the relationship loads perfectly but when I try a set of statements I get a message saying that I need WITH between MATCH and MERGE.

I have read up the stuff about WITH and I can see that I am mixing read and write statements without separating them properly, I can also see that aliasing comes into it - but for the life of me I can't see how to deal with it!

The first sheet looks like this and this generates the nodes nicely:
:
[image: Spreadsheet inc node generating Cypher statements]

The second sheet - for the relationships, looks like this:
[image: Spreadsheet inc relationship generating Cypher statements]

Any help at all would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Each of the statements your second sheet generates could be executed independently, since you don't reference any of the aliases from previous lines.

Or you could add a `WITH` to the end of each statement, clearing out the aliases in scope:

```
MATCH (a1{id:470}), (b1: {id: 48}) MERGE (a1)-[:HAS_ROD_ASSY]->(b1) WITH NULL AS _
MATCH (a2 {id:463}), (b2: {id: 584}) MERGE (a2)-[:ROD_FEATURES]->(b2) WITH NULL AS _
...
```

**LOAD CSV**

However, you might find the [`LOAD CSV` functionality](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/) in Cypher easier to work with.

Comment: Works a treat! Thank you very much!